# How to display Gujarati text in the JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, internationalization, jtable

**My code goes like this:**

This is the code used to create a `JTable` based on a search.

```
public void myMethod(){
    table_6 = new JTable(dataModel);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setBounds(16, 170, 1000, 300);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table_6);
    scrollPane.setVisible(true);
    table_6.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table_6.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table_6.setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table_6.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    table_6.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
}
```

Comment: You will need a font which is capable of rendering the characters.  Setting the font is a common enough task

Comment: `scrollPane.setBounds(16, 170, 1000, 300);` 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some Gujarati text in a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of either supplying a `Font` that supports rendering the glyphs of the language in question, or finding a compatible font on the system.

Example of the latter, for this machine (which has 250 fonts installed).

[image: Gujarati Text]

**Note:** Do not just select one of those fonts. It may not be available on the user's computer.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GujaratiText {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    String text = "તરસ્યો કૂતરો સાદડી પર બેસે છે";

    GujaratiText() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2,10,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));
        String[] fontFamilies = GraphicsEnvironment.
                getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        for(String fontFamily: fontFamilies) {
            Font font = new Font(fontFamily, Font.PLAIN, 20);
            if (font.canDisplayUpTo(text)<0) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
                label.setFont(font);
                ui.add(label);
                ui.add(new JLabel(fontFamily));
            }
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                GujaratiText o = new GujaratiText();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```